# Nativescript Angular Tabview navigation across tabs

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, tabview

I setup my NS app to used tabbed navigation with a login screen by following the writeup [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/implementing-a-login-for-nativescript-apps-with-tab-based-navigation).

I am trying to add a button to the players page that will navigate to the team details page for a specific team.

From what I have read it seems like it should be doable with something like this in the players component

```ts
toTeam( event: any ) {
        var teamId = event.object.team;
        this.router.navigate([
            '/tabs/default', { outlets: { teamTab: ['team', teamId] } }
        ])
    }
```

But every variation that I have tried results in `Error: Cannot match any routes`.

Does anybody know how to navigate across tabs/outlets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution mostly based on the information I got from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46443998/nativescript-navigate-between-router-outlets?rq=1) question. Things were slightly different because my app is using `<page-router-outlet>` instead of `<router-outlet>` and because of the overall structure of the app.

In the tabs component template I added an id to the bottom navigation so it could be referenced

```
<BottomNavigation id="bnav">
```

in the players component I added the following function:

```ts
toTeam( event: any ) {
        console.log("Team ID is: " + event.object.teamId);
        // Get the topmost frame so we can get the 'bnav' view from it later
        const topmostFrame: Frame = Frame.topmost();
        // Navigate places in the outlets
        this.re.navigate(
            [
                { 
                    outlets: {  
                        teamTab: ["team", event.object.teamId],
                        playerTab: ["players"], 
                    } 
                }
            ], { relativeTo: this.activeRoute.parent });
        // Get the tabview object from the page and switch it to show the teams tab
        let bNav:TabView = <TabView>topmostFrame.page.getViewById("bnav");
        bNav.selectedIndex = 1;
    }
```

The `<page-router-outlet>` meant I couldn't just import Page and use `this.page.getViewById("bnav")` because the page that the players component is contained within does not encompass the `<BottomNavigation>`. Getting the topmost frame allowed me to get the page that contained what I needed.

This all works perfectly in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your routing.module.ts, whether the route is defined. It needs to be done something like this.

```
        { path: '/tabs/default/:teamId', component: XYZComponent, outlet: 'team' },
```

Comment: My routing module contains `{path: "tabs", loadChildren: () => import("~/app/tabs/tabs.module").then(m => m.TabsModule)}` and then the tabs module contains the child routes just like in the writeup I followed. So as far as I understand all of the routes exist otherwise I wouldn't be able to navigate normally.